# How to obtain sequency specific in C++

Tags: c++, sequence

How to obtain the sequency specific in C++?

I need sequency: 1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8

and 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8

and 1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0

using counter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i, seq;
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ........
    }
    cout << seq << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I need Result:

1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,7,8,8,8

and

1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8

and

1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0

Answer (score 3):

Decompose `i` into `i / 4` and `i % 4`, and from there it should be pretty easy.